# Android Studio crashing on layout preview

Tags: layout, android-studio

Just ran into this problem recently. Cant find anything on web related to this. Does anyone have any idea? Studio crashed when the layout preview was loading. And this happens every time I try to see the preview. The layout doesn't have anything special, it consist of android design support tags. Would love to know what's going wrong. I'm using API 23

Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="#EEE" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/calendar_white"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have also the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I updated my Android sdk components and this didn't bug me after that.

Comment: How come this issue even appear ? I am also facing the same, no avail!